# x ** 1/3 in python?

Tags: python, root

Recently I encountered a problem:

I want to calculate various roots of various numbers like this:

```
x = x ** 1/y+1
```

None of the methods I know result in a working code.

Method 1:

```
x = 54
y = 2
x = x ** 1/y+1
print(x)
```

Printed value is 28.0 instead of 3.7798

Method 2:

```
x = 54
y = 2
x = x ** 1/(y+1)
print(x)
```

Printed value is 18.0 istead of 3.7798

Method 3:

```
x = 216
y = 2
x = x ** (1/(y+1))
print(x)
```

Printed value is 5.99 instead of 6

Is there a way that would work with y being up to 20?

Edit:

Another suggested method:

```
def nth_root(val, n):
    ret = int(val**(1./n))
    return ret + 1 if (ret + 1) ** n == val else ret

y = 1
print(nth_root(19, (y+1)))
```

prints 4

Comment: for starters, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: You should look up "operator precedence" for Python, which would indicate that you need the parentheses as shown in your 3rd attempt. As far as the 5.99 answer is concerned, I did not get that when I tried your example. I suspect there's more context to your scenario than you've described.

Comment: also, third example gives 6.0.

Comment: @njzk2 I get `5.999999999999999` in 3.4.

Comment: `5.999999999999999` in 3.5 too. I thought 3.x had the intelligent repr thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since everyone else has already told you why your Method 3 is correct, I'll stick to getting you an accurate answer. [You can read more about why you're not getting exactly 6](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/intro.html), but basically it's because your computer doesn't represent the 1/3 exactly when doing the calculation and makes the final answer off.

So, the easiest solution is to use sympy:

```
import sympy

y = 216
x = 2
x = sympy.root(y,x+1)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't seem to understand (yet) order of operations in a programming language.  You need parentheses to make sure you add 1 to y, *then* take the reciprocal, and *then* use that as an exponent.  The "natural" order is the opposite.

```
x = x ** (1.0/(y+1))
```

Comment: Well, no ... it must have been Python 3, in which division is floating point by default. Or the result would have been different.

Comment: x = 216
    y = 2
    x = x ** (1.0/(y+1))
    print(x)

still prints 5.9999

Comment: @Tom Zych: thanks; I've updated the answer.

Comment: There has to be something I'm missing... My last method looks exactly like yours just with .0 added. Even if I add the .0, I still get 5.99 printed. So is it that ,,I don't seem to understand'' or your way doesn't solve my problem either?

Comment: @MantasKandratavicius use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15978862/645956).

Comment: @grc Thanks for a new method but it either doesn't work or im doing something wrong again.

    def nth_root(val, n):
    ret = int(val**(1./n))
    return ret + 1 if (ret + 1) ** n == val else ret

y = 1
print(nth_root(19, (y+1)))

prints 4

Comment: If you want to guarantee exact arithmetic in integer cases, you need to use an integer-preserving algorithm.  Binary computers do not perform exact arithmetic: they round to the nearest binary representation, given their precision levels.  Trying printing the value of 1.0/3, and you'll see that it's not an infinite series of 3's; this is why the resulting operation comes up a little off your expectation.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is this (assuming you are using Python 3):

```
x = x ** (1/(y+1))
```

For Python 2, either of the following will work:

```
from __future__ import division
x = x ** (1/(y+1))
```

or (also fine on Python 3):

```
x = x ** (1.0/(y+1))
```

The issue is you need to apply the parentheses in the correct locations to get the order of operations right.

Method 3 is to do with floating point arithmetic. See: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

For more info on Python 2 vs. Python 3 division:
[Division in Python 2.7. and 3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21316968/division-in-python-2-7-and-3-3)

Comment: if the OP were using python 2, their 3rd example would ouptut 1, not 5.99

Comment: Correct. My solutions take that in to account. I will update the solution to clarify the logic errors in the OP's code too.

Comment: my point being that the op is not using python 2, which your solution assumes

Comment: Point taken. I'll edit the Python 2 part as reference only.

Answer (score 0):

Only your last code works because `**` has higher precedence than `/` (and `/` has higher precendence than `+`).

The value is not exactly 6, because floating point numbers are not perfectly accurate. A third can not be represented as a float.

Answer (score 0):

All your values are just as expected. According to the  [python operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

`x ** 1/y+1` is parsed as `((x ** 1) / y) + 1`, and

`x ** 1/(y+1)` is actually `(x ** 1) / (y + 1)`.

What you probably want is `x ** (1. / (y + 1))`.  Note, that `1.` is a floating point number, causing the whole expression to be evaluated as floats.  This also means that you will work with finite precision, e.g., getting `5.99999` instead fo `6` is to be expected.